# How to customize an external flow-typed definition file

Tags: javascript, jquery, flowtype, flow-typed

I'm using a flow-typed definition file but need to add the definitions for  plugins and see no way on how to do this ?

Let's say an npm module has an external flow-typed definition file that looks something like this:

```
declare class LibStatic {
  func1(): string;
}

declare module 'lib' {
  declare var exports: LibStatic;
}

declare var globalLib: LibStatic;
```

How would I customize the external flow-typed definition file, if a new method `func2` needs is dynamically added to `LibStatic` ?

Comment: Generally dynamically adding properties to existing types isn't really compatible with a static type system.

Comment: @loganfsmyth I'm not sure why this would no longer be static. I'm just looking for a way to add additional methods to be a predefined definition, but the result is a static type.

Comment: If the properties are already there in the library itself, then they should be in the definitions from `flow-typed`. If they aren't, then presumable either you added them, or the libraries exports are dynamic somehow. Either of those mean the exports aren't static.

Comment: I understand but in the case if jQuery, the definition from flow-typed only contains the core functionality and depending on the plugins that are configured the $ namespace can have additional methods that also need to be defined. How would you do this?

Comment: I can't say for your specific plugin, but normally I'd expect the module with the plugin behavior to be imported where you need it, with the export for that module defining the extended behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you are doing a *Bad Thing™*. Avoid mutating types after the fact, or you'll get into a mess and lose the benefits of static type-checking. With that said, you *could* tackle it as follows.

Create your own library, which re-exports everything from `LibStatic`. You can add your new methods there and have full control over the exported types. Now use your own library everywhere you were previously using `LibStatic`.

Comment: Why would this be a bad thing? The concrete use case for my questions is actually jQuery and the plugin system. The default jQuery type definition file contains the core components but depending on the plugins installed additional methods can be made available.